# How can I fix 301 error using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, http, https

I am just beginning to learn how to use sockets in python. I am trying to create a get request to "python.org" but I keep on getting "301" error. If anyone knows why please help.

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'www.python.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        request = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n' % hostname
        ssock.send(request.encode())
        response = ssock.recv(6000)
        print(response)
```

EDIT: I am currently getting this response

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Can anyone help with this error?

Got it working with this code:

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'www.python.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:

    try:
        context.check_hostname = False
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    except:
        None

    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        request = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n' % hostname
        ssock.send(request.encode())
        response = ssock.recv(6000)
        print(response)
```

Comment: You're probably getting a redirect response telling you to visit the site over HTTPS (port 80 to port 443). Why use raw sockets for HTTP and not a library?

Comment: Because I am trying to create my own lib with tls and ja3 implementation. And later on add in h2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

301 HTTP code is Moved Permanently not a error. For this resources, you need use with another link (current is `/`, it define in first line `GET / HTTP`). It define in your response `http_response` .

Comment: Use another link? Why would I need to use another link?

Comment: Because your HTTP server. `301 HTTP code is Moved Permanently` redirect to another link. It define in your response `http_response`